# Intuition behind the PMF of multinomial distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multinomial-distribution, intuition

The combinatorial coefficient of the binomial distribution given by : $\binom{n}{x}$ which shows the number of times $x$ successes can occur in $n$ trials.

In case of a multinomial distribution the combinatorial coefficient is given by: $\frac{n!}{x_{1}!x_{2}!...x_{k}!}$. Intuitively, I feel that this coefficient represents the number of times in $n$ trials event $X_{1}$ occurs $x_{1}$ times, event $X_{2}$ occurs $x_{2}$ times and so on.

However, I was wondering how one can mathematically show that this is indeed the case?

I tried to arrive at this generalization by first writing $\binom{n}{x}$ as $\frac{n!}{x!y!}$ where $y! = (n-x)!$ but I am looking for a more mathematically rigorous interperetation.

Comment: **Hint**: think of the multiplication rule of events and the product $$ \binom{n}{n_1} \binom{n-n_1}{n_2} \ldots \binom{n-n_1-\ldots-n_{k-2}}{n_{k-1}}$$

Comment: The group of permutations of the $n$ trials acts on them. The subgroup which preserves the data is isomorphic to the product of the permutation groups of the $x_j$ events of type $X_j$.  Having made these two trivial observations, the result follows immediately from the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma).

Answer (score 2):

First pick the locations of object 1. This gives $\binom{n}{x_1}$ combinations. Now pick locations of object 2, from the remaining $n-x_1$ locations. This gives $\binom{n-x_1}{x_2}$ combinations for object 2. Thus we have $\binom{n}{x_1}\binom{n-x_1}{x_2}=\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!(n-x_1-x_2)!}$ ways of picking the locations of the first two objects. You now pick object 3 locations from $n-x_1-x_2$ possible slots... Do this for all of the $k$ objects and you'll arrive at the result.